# Parameter representation python

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, gradient-descent

I know this can be interpreted as vague but I have to ask. I am working on a problem where theta is denoted by θ = {W,C,b} where W is a matrix of size d*d, C is a vector belonging to R^d and b is a real number.

θ here is the same as you will see in other ML problems, I will be applying the derivative of the loss function parametrized by θ [then I will be updating the θ using Gradient Descent], and I want to understand how it is supposed to be represented in code. Is it a matrix, or do I separate the elements for different equations?

Later on in the assignment we are supposed to compute the loss function f(X,y;θ+0.01*c), c being some vector if I don't represent θ correctly I don't know how to present some addition component with it as stated above.